# In Sql, for a senior manager, if the employee is also a manager, then update its manager to employee name

Tags: sql, sql-server

Below is my data. Consider the letter as unique employees. Example for Senior Manager(SM)- A. I have employee who is also a manager. Then I want to update the Manager column to same as Employee. For Senior Manager B, No employee is a manager so dont have to do anything. How do I update the Manager column?
Expected Result below.

Data:

```
 Senior Manager Manager Employee

    A           NULL    X
    A           NULL    Y
    A           NULL    Z
    A           X       C
    A           Y       D
    A           Z       E
    B           NULL    F
    B           NULL    G
```

**Expected Result**:

```
 Senior Manager Manager Employee
    A           X       X
    A           Y       Y
    A           Z       Z
    A           X       C
    A           Y       D
    A           Z       E
    B           NULL    F
    B           NULL    G
```

Comment: You've told us what you want to do here, but haven't asked a question. What is it your asking here? What have you tried so far, and why didn't it work? I'd also suggest taking the time to format your sample data and expected results; which are somewhat untidy and difficult to read right now. Thanks.

Comment: updated. I want to update the manager column only if employee is also a manager  otherwise keep it as null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a little self-join action here with a `COALESCE()` should get you in the ballpark:

```
SELECT Employee.[Senior Manager], 
    COALESCE(Employee.[Manager], [Manager].[Manager]) as [Manager], 
    Employee.Employee
FROM [Table] as [Employee]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [Table] as [Manager]
        ON [Employee].[Employee] = [Manager].[Manager]
```